# Replace values from Select query in SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My SQL query is:

```
GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
GridView1.DataBind();

DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OfficeConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Consulting ", con))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adpt.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I have a table with a few columns and what I am trying to achieve is to display the data in a `GridView`.  At the moment the data is displayed in my `GridView` but I would like to replace text in the columns and then display in the `gridview`

So for example this is my table:

```
| DisplayName | $_License           
+-------------+------------------------
| User 1      | TestLicense:License1   |
| User 2      | TestLicense:License2   |
```

So in my `Gridview` I would to display:

```
| Display Name | License Type           |
+--------------+------------------------+
| User 1       | License1               |
| User 2       | License2               |
```

Note that the`Display Name` has a space and the `$_License` is changed to `License Type` and the row is changed from `TestLicense:License1` to `License1`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `select DisplayName as "Display Name", ...` to get that space in the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
"SELECT DisplayName 'Display Name',  Replace($_License,'TestLicense:', '')  'License Type' Name  FROM Consulting "
```

Comment: Hi, have tried it but getting error now `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid pseudocolumn "$_".'`

Comment: Try this:  "SELECT DisplayName 'Display Name',  Replace([$_License],'TestLicense:', '')  'License Type' Name  FROM Consulting "

Comment: Thanks, but now it just says `'Invalid column name '$_License'.'`  But the column name is there

Answer (score 0):

Modify your select query as per required result:

```
SELECT DisplayName  AS 'Display Name' , RIGHT($_License, LEN($_License) - 11) AS 'License Type' FROM Consulting;
```